# Ubuntu 14.04: no sftp-access because of bad ownership or modes

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, ownership

I have a problem connecting to my ubuntu 14.04 server via sftp. Everytime I try to connect, I get this info/error messages:

```
Sep 18 15:04:47 localhost sshd[2917]: Accepted password for junperbo from      87.129.13.92 port 59333 ssh2
Sep 18 15:04:47 localhost sshd[2917]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user junperbo by (uid=0)
Sep 18 15:04:47 localhost systemd-logind[2427]: Removed session 2.
Sep 18 15:04:47 localhost systemd-logind[2427]: New session 3 of user junperbo.
Sep 18 15:04:48 localhost sshd[2954]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/var/www/"
Sep 18 15:04:48 localhost sshd[2917]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user junperbo
```

I'm new to managing my Ubuntu server, so please be detailed in your answers. I know that the problem can be solved with "chmod" or/and "chown", but how?

Please keep in mind, that I have edited my sshd_config with this Subsystem:

```
Subsystem sftp internatl-sftp
Match group ftpaccess
AllowUsers junperbo
ChrootDirectory /var/www/%u
PasswordAuthentication yes
x11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Users with ftp-access shoul be member of the ftpaccess group. User are added with this command:

```
sudo adduser USERNAME --ingroup ftpaccess --no-create-home --shell=/bin/false
```

"ls -la /var/www" gives me the following output

```
total 20
drwxrwx---  5 root     root      4096 Sep 18 06:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root     root      4096 Sep 16 16:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2     1002 ftpaccess 4096 Sep 18 06:27 domainx
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root      4096 Sep 16 16:15 html
drwxr-xr-x  2 junperbo ftpaccess 4096 Sep 18 06:45 junperbo
```

The aim is to simply add new users to the ftpaccess group with the command above. If possible, I don't want to add every new user to my sshd_conf.

How can I solve this problems?

Thanks,
Brotzka

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is manual page for `sshd_config(5)` and it contains all information for all you want to set up your server. For you, there is important part about chroot directory:

> #### ChrootDirectory
>
> Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after authentication.  **At session startup sshd(8) checks that all components of the pathname are root-owned directories which are not writable by any other user or group.**  After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home directory.

This means that you need to execute:

```
chown root:root /var/www
chmod go-w /var/www
```

Comment: What do you mean with "go-w"? "chown go-w /var/www" gives me this error back: "chown: invalid user: 'go-w'"

Comment: Sorry, got it. You ment "chmod go-w /var/www". Now I can connect, but I am not able to create files/folders, which makes the ftp-access useless to me

Comment: Sorry. I meant `chmod`. It was not what you wanted. The chroot directory must have the above mentioned attributes. But you can create directories inside, that are writable by your user!