# Jail user in SFTP + SSH

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, debian, chroot

I want to jail an "normal" user with the special group `developer` for SFTP and SSH.

The user can only navigate in `/srv/DEVELOPMENT` (SSH/SFTP) **AND** over SSH, the user can only execute a limit of commands (see the script at the bottom).

**Why i want this?**

I work on a little project. Last days, another developers wan't to support the project with their experiences. The developer can be edit the "developer-website" and can start/stop/restart an `Node.js` application over SSH. The next think is: The user must use the shell to change their account password.

Currently, i have configured the SSH-Deamon with following steps:

**Jail over SFTP**

```
Match Group developer
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding yes
    ChrootDirectory /srv/DEVELOPMENT
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

The user was added by following commands/options:

```
useradd --base-dir /srv/ --home-dir /srv/ --no-user-group --shell /srv/shell.sh $USERNAME
usermod -G developer $USERNAME
id $USERNAME
passwd $USERNAME
```

**Current Directory Permissions**

```
/srv               developer:root   0755
/srv/DEVELOPMENT   developer:root   0750
/srv/DEVELOPMENT/* developer:root   0777
```

With `SFTP` it work's correctly. The **second part** to jail the user over SSH is currently little bit harder. This step won't work currently, **and thats is my question**.

The chroot is limited on `internal-sfpt`. When i try to login, the connection will be aborted with the message, that the connection is only allowed for sftp:

```
ssh TestUser@example.com
TestUser@example.com's password:
This service allows sftp connections only.
Connection to example.com closed.
```

Here, i had remove `ForceCommand` on the SSH-Deamon config > The Login will be succeed.

**But here is my problem**

When i try to login, no executables cant be used:

```
ssh TestUser@example.com
TestUser@example.com's password:
Linux example.com 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u2 (2017-06-26) x86_64
Last login: Sun Jul 30 18:00:11 2017 from ****************
/srv/shell.sh: No such file or directory
Connection to example.com closed.
```

`/srv/shell.sh` is a custom shell-script to limit the commands, for sample:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    commands=("man" "passwd" "ls" "account", "whoami", "clear", "cd")

    RED='\033[0;31m'
    YELLOW='\033[0;33m'
    MAGENTA='\033[0;35m'
    CYAN='\033[0;36m'
    NC='\033[0m' # No Color
    INDENTATION='   '

    SYSTEM_UPTIME=`uptime --pretty`
    SYSTEM_USERS=`who -q`
    SYSTEM_QUOTA="None"
    SYSTEM_RAM="None"

    timestamp(){
        date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    }

    log(){
        echo -e "[$(timestamp)]\t$1\t$(whoami)\t$2" >> /var/log/developer-user/shell.log;
    }

    execute() {
        # EXIT
        if [[ "$ln" == "exit" ]] || [[ "$ln" == "q" ]]
        then
            exit

        # HELP
        elif [[ "$ln" == "help" ]]
        then
            echo "Type exit or q to quit."
            echo "Commands you can use:"
            echo "  account"
            echo "  help"
            echo "  echo"
            echo "  man <ManPage>"
            echo "  passwd"
            echo "  ls"
            echo "  clear"
            echo "  cd"

        # CD
        elif [[ "$ln" =~ ^cd\ .*$ ]]
        then
            LAST=`pwd`

            $ln

            CURRENT=`pwd`

            if [[ $CURRENT == "/srv" ]]
            then
                log CHANGE_DIR FAILED_PERMISSIONS "$ln"
                echo -e "${RED}ERROR:${NC} Sorry, you can't change to the previous directory ${YELLOW}\"${CURRENT}\"${NC}."
                cd $LAST

            elif [[ ! "$CURRENT" =~ ^/srv/DEVELOPMENT ]]
            then
                log CHANGE_DIR FAILED_PERMISSIONS "$ln"
                echo -e "${RED}ERROR:${NC} Sorry, you can't change to the directory ${YELLOW}\"${CURRENT}\"${NC}."
                cd $LAST

            elif [[ `stat -c "%G" ${CURRENT}` == "friendlounge" ]]
            then
                log CHANGE_DIR "$ln"

            else
                log CHANGE_DIR FAILED_PERMISSIONS "$ln"
                echo -e "${RED}ERROR:${NC} You have no permissions on ${YELLOW}\"${CURRENT}\"${NC}."
                cd $LAST
            fi
        # ECHO
        elif [[ "$ln" =~ ^echo\ .*$ ]]
        then
            $ln
            log COMMAND "$ln"

        # ACCOUNT
        elif [[ "$ln" = "account" ]]
        then
            echo -e "YOUR ACCOUNT:"
            echo -e "Username: $(whoami)"

        # OTHERS
        else
            ok=false
            for cmd in "${commands[@]}"
            do
                if [[ "$cmd" == "$ln" ]]
                then
                    ok=true
                fi
            done
            if $ok
            then
                $ln
            else
                echo -e "${RED}ERROR:${NC} You have no permissions to execute ${YELLOW}\"${ln}\"${NC}."
                log DENIED "$ln"
            fi
        fi
    }

    # WELCOME MESSAGE
    echo -e "${INDENTATION}${MAGENTA}Account:${NC}${INDENTATION}$(whoami)"
    echo -e "${INDENTATION}${MAGENTA}Date:${NC}${INDENTATION}${INDENTATION}$(timestamp)"
    echo -e "${INDENTATION}${MAGENTA}Uptime:${NC}${INDENTATION}${INDENTATION}${SYSTEM_UPTIME}"
    echo -e "${INDENTATION}${MAGENTA}Users:${NC}${INDENTATION}${INDENTATION}${SYSTEM_USERS}"
    echo -e "${INDENTATION}${MAGENTA}Quota:${NC}${INDENTATION}${INDENTATION}${SYSTEM_QUOTA}"
    echo -e "${INDENTATION}${MAGENTA}RAM:${NC}${INDENTATION}${INDENTATION}${SYSTEM_RAM}"

    log LOGIN "$@"
    cd
    trap "trap=\"\";log LOGOUT;exit" EXIT

    # Optionally check for '-c custom_command' arguments passed directly to shell
    # Then you can also use ssh user@host custom_command, which will execute /root/rbash.sh
    if [[ "$1" == "-c" ]]
    then
        shift
        execute "$@"
    else
        while echo -e -n "${RED}$(whoami)${YELLOW}@${CYAN}$(hostname) ${YELLOW}$(pwd) ${MAGENTA}#${NC} " && read ln
        do
            execute "$ln"
        done
    fi
```

This shell-script checks the `permission` of the user and force only to the `/srv/DEVELOPMENT` directory or subdirectorys.

It's irrelevant to set another login-shells like `/bin/bash` or other - On each login, the SSH-Demon close the connection after the error message `XXXX: No such file or directory`.

I had try to set different permissions and other. i can't resolve the problem to connect over ssh.

Anyone have an idea?

**Before you answer**

- yes, i known the possible security reasons (for sample, to manage the permissions over my "own" shell-login-script)
- no, i don't want to install huge alternatives like `schroot` or `jailkit` (found on google, reading the first minutes says, that these alternatives uses a completely decoupled system like a virtual-machine(?) - inform me, when it's wrong with explicit informations)

Comment: When you say /srv/shell.sh do you mean /srv/DEVELOPMENT/srv/shell.sh?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32653528/2196426

Comment: @spinkus no, i mean /srv/shell.sh.

Comment: @Jakuje it's not an duplicate. Read your linked question.

Comment: It is. You have a chroot directory owned by `developer`, which is wrong.

Comment: I had change the permission on the directorys. It must be root:developer with 750, otherwise i get the error on your linked question.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, It's is very easy to use.

you can jail a user in 3 steps.

1. add user
2. create a jail with a simple configuration file.
3. jail this user.

The tool is located at :https://github.com/pymumu/jail-shell